# Typing for a class decorator when the wrapper has an instance variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy

Is this decorator typed correctly, given the current limits of mypy? I include example usage below:

```py
import functools
from typing import TypeVar, Type, Any, cast

C = TypeVar('C', bound=Type[Any])


def singleton(cls: C) -> C:
    """Transforms a class into a Singleton (only one instance can exist)."""

    @functools.wraps(cls)
    def wrapper(*args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> Any:
        if not wrapper.instance:  # type: ignore  # https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/2087
            wrapper.instance = cls(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore  # https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/2087
        return wrapper.instance  # type: ignore  # https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/2087

    wrapper.instance = None  # type: ignore  # https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/2087
    return cast(C, wrapper)


@singleton
class Test:
    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = Test()
    b = Test()
    print(a is b)
```

I had to add `type: ignore` on the lines where the `instance` attribute appears because otherwise mypy would flag these errors:

`error: "Callable[..., Any]" has no attribute "instance"`

Comment: I didn't see any errors, the code runs perfectly.  May I know the python version you are running?

Comment: it runs well, but I'm curious if the typing done on the code is correct. That's the question.

Comment: As recently explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55157875/4134674), the `singleton` decorator does not return a class, but a function (namely `wrapper`) that returns instances of the decorated class when called. Hence the correct way to decorate `singleton` imho rather looks like `def singleton(cls: Type[C]) -> Callable[[Tuple[Any], Dict[str, Any]], C]:`. Still, doesn't solve the issue with extra attributes on callables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function takes an argument of type `C` and returns a result of the same type. Therefore, according to mypy `a` and `b` will have the same type. You can check it with `reveal_type`.

```py
reveal_type(a) # Revealed type is 'test.Test'
reveal_type(b) # Revealed type is 'test.Test'
```

---

Anyway both `cast` and `# type: ignore` should be used with caution, because they are telling mypy to trust you (the developer) that the types are correct even if it cannot confirm it.

The potential problem I see with your code is that you are substituting a class (i.e. `Test`) with a function, and this could break some code. For example:

```py
>>> Test
<function Test at 0x7f257dd2bae8>
>>> Test.mro()
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'mro'
```

An other approach you could try is to substitute the `__new__` method of the decorated class:

```py
def singleton(cls: C) -> C:
    """Transforms a class into a Singleton (only one instance can exist)."""

    new = cls.__new__

    def _singleton_new(cls, *args, **kwds):
        try:
            inst = cls._instance
        except AttributeError:
            cls._instance = inst = new(cls, *args, **kwds)
        return inst

    cls.__new__ = _singleton_new
    return cls
```

In this case you are not replacing the whole class, and therefore you are less likely to break other code using the class:

```py
>>> Test                                                                                                                                                   
test.Test

>>> Test.mro()                                                                                                                                                           
[test.Test, object]
```

Note that the above code is just an example to show the limitations of your current approach. Therefore, you should probably not use it as is, but look for a more solid solution.

Comment: Any idea why I get `>           cls._instance = inst = new(cls, *args, **kwargs)`
`E           TypeError: object.__new__() takes no arguments` when I try to create an instance with arguments?

Comment: It seems to be working for me, could you post a link to the code?