# Clarification on why decorator only called once

Tags: python, singleton, decorator

I'm confused about this code I got from [here](https://realpython.com/primer-on-python-decorators/):

```
import functools

def singleton(cls):
    """Make a class a Singleton class (only one instance)"""
    @functools.wraps(cls)
    def wrapper_singleton(*args, **kwargs):
        if not wrapper_singleton.instance:
            wrapper_singleton.instance = cls(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper_singleton.instance
    print('****')
    wrapper_singleton.instance = None
    return wrapper_singleton

@singleton
class TheOne:
    pass
```

Why doesn't `wrapper_singleton.instance = None` set the instance to none each time the class is instantiated? I put a print statement above this line and it only gets called once also. Thanks

```
>>> first_one = TheOne()
>>> another_one = TheOne()

>>> id(first_one)
140094218762280

>>> id(another_one)
140094218762280

>>> first_one is another_one
True
```

Comment: Because `singleton` only gets called once, right here: `@singleton`. It's never called anywhere else. Note, there is a bug here, if the class implements `__bool__` to return false, it will generate a new instance. They probably should have said `if wrapper_singleton.instance is not None:`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why doesn't `wrapper_singleton.instance = None` set the instance to none
>   each time the class is instantiated?

Because that part of the code is only executed the when class is decorated.
This:

```
@singleton
class TheOne:
    pass
```

is functionally equivalent to

```
class TheOne:
    pass

TheOne = singleton(TheOne)
```

Both versions of the code actually return a function through the magic of `functools.wraps`, that acts as if it was the wrapped callable, as [@smarie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7262247/smarie) excellently explains [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55102697/4134674).

```
TheOne = singleton(TheOne)
print(TheOne)
# <function TheOne at 0x00000000029C4400>
```

If you remove the `@functools.wraps` decoration, you have a superficial look behind the scenes:

```
def singleton(cls)
    #@functools.wraps(cls)
    def wrapper_singleton(*args, **kwargs): ...

TheOne = singleton(TheOne)
print(TheOne)
# <function singleton.<locals>.wrapper_singleton at 0x00000000029F4400>
```

So the name `TheOne` is actually assigned to the inner function `wrapper_singleton` of your `singleton` function.
Hence when you do `TheOne()`, you don't instantiate the class directly, you call `wrapper_singleton` which does that for you.
This means, that the function `singleton` is only called when you decorate the class or do that manually via `TheOne = singleton(TheOne)`. It defines `wrapper_singleton`, creates an additional attribute `instance` on it (so that `if not wrapper_singleton.instance` doesn't raise an AttributeError) and then returns it under the name `TheOne`.

You can break the singleton by decorating the class again.

```
class TheOne:
    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.arg = arg

TheOne = singleton(TheOne)
t1 = TheOne(42)
print(t1.arg, id(t1))
# 42 43808640

# Since this time around TheOne already is wrapper_singleton, wrapped by functools.wraps,
# You have to access your class object through the __wrapped__ attribute
TheOne = singleton(TheOne.__wrapped__)
t2 = TheOne(21)
print(t2.arg, id(t2))
# 21 43808920
```